# postgres pg_statio: difference between heap_blks_hit and idx_blks_hit

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics

I am interested in query:

```
    create or replace view iostat as select blk.relname
    as relname,blk.heap_blks_read || ':' || blk.heap_blks_hit as heap_blk,
            blk.idx_blks_read || ':' || blk.idx_blks_hit as idx_blk,
            tpl.seq_scan || ':' || tpl.seq_tup_read as seq_tup,
            tpl.idx_scan || ':' || tpl.idx_tup_fetch as idx_tup
    from  pg_statio_user_tables blk JOIN  pg_stat_user_tables tpl
    USING (relname);
```

What is the difference in all pairs? And what do all of them mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, "heap" is not to be confused with the Computer Science term of "heap," which refers to a data structure or segment of memory.  In PostgreSQL, "heap" refers to the data file(s) related to a particular table.  Columns prefixed with `idx_` refer to indexes created to speed up the lookup of data (in the heap).

To answer your question about the meaning of the pairs, I would describe them in this way:

- `heap_blk` would be the ratio between 8KB blocks of a table read from disk `:` 8KB blocks of a table read from cache
- `idx_blk` would be the ratio between 8KB blocks of all indexes of "this table" (represented by `relname`) read from disk `:` 8KB blocks of all indexes of "this table" read from cache
- `seq_tup` would be the ratio between number of sequential scans performed on "this table" `:` number of rows/tuples read from "this table" (since the last `pg_reset_stats()` call)
- `idx_tup` would be the ratio between number of index scans performed on "this table" `:` number of rows/tuples fetched after referencing an index

More details on each of the columns of `pg_statio_user_tables` can be found [in the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html)